# What does upgrading gradle and gradle plugin change / influence in an app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to upgrade the build.gradle of an app.

```
Gradle Version: 4.4  
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 3.1.0
```

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.learn.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 68
        versionName "2.2 - 135"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk { abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64" }
        //PASSAGGIO DA VERSIONE 32-BIT A 64-BIT, VEDI https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit
        //ndk.abiFilters = 'armeabi-v7a' 'arm64-v8a' 'x86' 'x86_64'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

I know I shouldn't fiddle with the `minSdkVersion`,`targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion`, since the target device uses API 26.
What I'm trying to understand is:

- What changes does upgrading the `Gradle Version` and `Gradle Plugin Version` bring? I've tried upgrading them, and while the app compiles and works, the .apk is 20Mb, from 12Mb with the old Gradle & Plugin versions

I'm using the last version of Android (3.6.1 now)

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted my comment after re-reading that bit myself. Thank you.

Comment: no problem, stack overflow works best if you ask one question at a time, otherwise your post becomes quite broad, so you might want to remove that from your original question :)

Comment: So from what I understand, ```compileSdkVersion``` (which is dependent on the ```targetSdkVersion``` ) and ```buildToolsVersion``` are used for building the app / .apk, and are not included in the .apk, since the device has the SDK / compile already. Is this corect?